# Why does this Javascript 'fetch' call fail?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am prototyping a simple web app front end that needs to fetch JSON data from my server.  The server itself works fine -- I can click on the link, and the JSON data shows up in the browser.  But the following simple script fails:

```
    fetch('https://x.x.x.x:8000')   //  MY URL FAILS
    // fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')  // ALTERNATE URL WORKS
    .then(function() {
        alert("Successful")
    })
    .catch(function() {
        alert("Failure")
    });
```

Originally, I thought the problem was with the use of a self-signed certificate, but I have now configured it to use a trusted certificate -- as confirmed by Google Chrome's security diagnostic -- yet the script still throws the 'fail' alert.

I'm a novice JS programmer with zero prior front-end development experience, so I may be overlooking something obvious.

I'll temporarily post the actual link in a comment below, in case anyone wants to try it.

EDIT:  Here are the errors I see in the browser console.  I'm not familiar enough with developer tools to know where else to look.

[image]

Comment: TEMPORARY Actual link:  https://precip.aos.wisc.edu:8000/?lat=43&lon=-89
Clicking on this link successfully retrieves a JSON response.

Comment: Any other information in your dev console when you try the fetch? Possibly a "cross origin resource sharing" error?

Comment: check the network tab in the devtools. Also, catch gets passed an error. Log it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but possibly, you are fetching `https://x.x.x.x:8000`. Did you set a route for `/`, the URL's base? Or is it something else like `/add` or `/get`? If yes,
fetch that. i.e, `https://x.x.x.x:8000'/add` or `https://x.x.x.x:8000'/get`.

It could also be a CORS error. Try adding this to your fetch body:

```js
  fetch(url, {
    mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
```

Comment: Your suggestion to add the no-cors mode seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cross origin resource error. But you can debug it yourself by adding some logging to your catch.

```
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err)
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Speaking as a novice, how do I solve this?  The server is running on a remote machine, and I'm trying to write a simple (and portable) web front-end that will process and display the fetched data.

Comment: you need to either set the server to accept CORS requests (for example, if it's a node.js server https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html), or add `no-cors` to your request. Mastermind has provided an example below that may work.

Comment: yep any of that works